# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `logger` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-cli

I'm trying to run webpack along with webpack-dev-server but having this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `logger` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/monz777/test/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/createConfig.js:4:34)
at Module._compile (/Users/monz777/test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
at require (/Users/monz777/test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (Users/monz777/test/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/startDevServer.js:6:40)
at Module._compile (/Users/monz777/test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
```

Versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.42.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
```

NPM script:

```
"start": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.config.js",
```

Was trying the same on the latest versions, but didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before, then i tried these versions. And it works!

```
"webpack": "^4.41.5",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

NPM script

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"start": "webpack serve --open 'Google Chrome'" //webpack serve --open 'browser-name'
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me.
Maybe that shoud be reported to the webpack github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Also I tried to remove completely node_modules and call npm i again. It didn't help, but when I started to install modules one by one, it worked out. Looks like there was some conflicted issue across modules.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on:

```
"webpack": "^4.42.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
```

I tried to reinstall 「webpack-cli」

```
yarn add webpack-cli@4.2.0
```

Retry package.json script:

```
"start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js"
```

Is worked out!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package.json` file.
2. Recreating the `package.json` file using the `npm init -y` command.
3. Reinstalling the packages (in this case I'm installing some extra packages as I'm assuming you will eventually need to use `.css`, `.html` and `.js` files as well) with the following command: `npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server html-webpack-plugin style-loader css-loader file-loader`.

You should then be able to run webpack again.